# regular expression for csv numbers from 1 to 4096

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that can match a string of numbers from 1 to 4096 separated by commas.
I have a regix that check number 1-1000 but not sure how to change it to check if number is less then 4096

This will allow whitespaces after commas:

^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000)(,\s*([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|1000))*$

Comment: Isn't any of 1-1000 less than 4096?

Comment: yes but this regix will not accept anything above 1000 aswell. it will not accept 1001 or 2202 that is less then 4096 aswell and valid values.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a valid and non-valid input so we can help you ?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot evaluate as an integer?

Comment: Are the numbers padded? e.g. zero padded `0001, 0002` or space padded `   1,   2`

Comment: @MaroxTn
24,233,1023,1233,4432  is valid
23 is valid
24,4097 is invalid
anything other then a number is invalid

Comment: @Melioratus that check is already in my regex. that first digit should be a non-zero numer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
^(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40([0-8][0-9]|9[0-6]))(,\s*[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|[1-3][0-9][0-9][0-9]|40([0-8][0-9]|9[0-6]))*)$
```

Fixed?

Comment: Just for fun (because I agree much with others, regular expression is designed for other purposes) I've constructed it also:

`^((?:\b(?:\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d\d|[1-3]\d\d\d|40[0-8][0-9]|409[0-5])\b,?)+)$`

of course \d may be replaced with [0-9]

Comment: @zolo - I agree. Fun regexp puzzle but I would use code in real life not a regexp. I had fun figuring it out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a problem for a regex.
If you have a string of numbers separated by commas then convert them to an array and filter them like numbers instead of bothering with a regex.

```js
var nums = "1,4,7,900,4097,4095";
var result = nums.split(",").filter(function(v){
  return v < 4096;
});
console.log(result);
```

If you can't validate your input text then you can filter out non-numbers on the fly...

```js
var nums = "1,4,7,900,4097,'bob',4095";
var result = nums.split(",").filter(function(v){
  var testVal = parseInt(v);
  return testVal != NaN && testVal < 4096;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i have reasons to use regex. one them is that input field entry works well with regex rather than writing code for it.

Comment: Use the pattern attribute to check that nothing other than numbers and commas are entered, then use this code to check its validity.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression will only make it more complicated for you, you can use this :

```
 function matchStr(ch){

     var str = ch.split(",");  //Split the string to an array
     for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){  //Go through the integers

        if(parseInt(str[i]) > 4096 || parseInt(str[i]) < 0) //If the integer is bigger that 4096
           return false;

     }

     return true;
 }
```